# How to get mail report about all unhandled exceptions inside of twisted server?

Tags: python, debugging, twisted

I'm initialize 2 servers in one twisted script. So I want to get all unhadled exception inside of it on my mail. Is it posible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sys.excepthook`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook). `sys.excepthook` catches all exceptions that are uncaught in your code. How you handle them from there is your choice.

For sending emails, you may be interested in the Python [email](http://docs.python.org/library/email.html) module. Here are some [examples](http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html).

You can reconstruct a traceback from an exception using the Python [traceback](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exception) module; specifically [`format_exception()`](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exception).

```
import sys
import traceback

def excepthook(type_, value, tb):
    # do whatever with the exception information
    # you want to do here

    exception = traceback.format_exception(type_, value, tb)
    print ''.join(exception)

sys.excepthook = excepthook
```

Note: I don't know anything about twisted, so there may be a twisted way (pun not intended) to do this, however, this is how I would do it if there was no other official way of course.

Comment: Thank. It's a good idea. I'll test today and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: How're you doing it? Any code samples which demonstrate the issue? Are you sure that the code itself isn't at fault, vs this way of doing it?